# How to Improve Oracle Query Performance when use ListAggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to Display fees for every records I have 13000 records.and I need to Display fees 100+300+500=900. SO I used List Aggregate function when i Use List Aggregate I need to give a order by (Syntax) it Affects My Query Performance
My Query is below

```
SELECT
  (SELECT REPLACE(ListAgg(amount,',')within groupby(
  ORDER BY Auditcomptranid),',','+')
    ||'=
    ||SUM(amount)AS Fees
  FROM Audit_comp_trans
  WHERE Audit_comp_trans.SSU_ID=SSU_Request.SSU_ID
  AND Audit_comp_trans.Aucompid= SSU_Request.Aucompid
  )
FROM SSU_Request
INNER JOIN comp_infromation
ORDER BY SSU_ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to split the task in two steps.

In the first place define the subquery providing the grouping column and the fee column (I use subquery factoring in my example, you must modify it to your source tables).

For the second step, the formatting of the formula you may use the `ListAgg` function, but you must follow the [syntax rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030). The example below illustrates the usage:

```
with tab as (
-- your query here
-- providing the group column and fee column
select group_id, fee ....

)
select group_id,
listagg(fee,' + ') within group (order by fee) ||
' = ' || sum(fee) as fees
from tab
group by group_id
```

Comment: It Works but when I add Order by Query performance goes down Please suggest me

Comment: @MaheshwaranRagunathan there is no such thing as a general help with performance problems. You'll have to look at [execution plan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601) and gain a basic understanding of the difference between getting the first row from unsorted and sorted row source (which might be your case)